# Remove some junk characters from file in unix

Tags: unix

I have a file in unix with following contents-

Juhix1xjuhi_sinha@infosys.com;Jayabratax1xjayabrata_saha@infosys.com;Animeshx1xanimesh_panda@infosys.com;Davinderx1xdavinder_khurana@infosys.com;Sambitx1xsambit_das01@infosys.com;Kiranx1xkiran_inupakolla@infosys.com

I want to remove the PATTERN Jayabratax1xjayabrata_saha@infosys.com; from adresses given above.

Can someone help me how can I remove them using sed or cut in UNIX?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on `unix.stackexchange.com`!

Answer (score 0):

Is perl und not sec but i think it will help you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

open $OUT '>', 'mail.txt' or die'Cant open file';

$str = <your_Str>;

@mails = split /;/,$str;

while(pop @mails){
    print $OUT $_;
}

close($OUT);
```